# Restrict access to route with routeprovider unless variable as been set

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm in the process of learning AngularJS, working on a more in-depth ToDo app. I'm having an issue with trying to limit access to a url or "route" using angular.

When you hit my dev url on my machine (todo.ang) it brings you to todo.ang/#/home, on this view you see the categories which have todos associated to each. EG (category = cat, cat has a todo of "feed", and "play"), when you click a category I'm calling the $scope.goToCategory function (seen in my JS fiddle) which sets a variable for my firebase ref then redirects you too /#/todo. This is working correctly.

My problem is, I don't want the user to be able to access /#/todo if the todoRef variable is still undefined. But it seems like even after $scope.goToCategory is called and todoRef is set to a firebase URL, the routerprovider never gets recalled to know that todoRef has been set to a different value so it always forces you back to /#/home.

code:

```
var todoRef = undefined; 

if (todoRef !== undefined) {
   $routeProvider.when('/todo', {
   templateUrl: 'views/todo.html',
   controller: 'TodoCtrl'
   });
}

$scope.goToCategory = function(catId) {
   test = catId;
   todoRef = new Firebase("URL HERE");
   $location.path('/todo');
}
```

I didn't include the entire file of code but if thats necessary, I can do that as well.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89q4vL6p/)

Comment: You need to either reproduce the issue in fiddle or post full code. Your fiddle is useless right now.

Comment: my applogies, heres a live example

http://charliebois.com/angular/

and updated the fiddle with my app.js where everything is happening.

http://jsfiddle.net/89q4vL6p/1/

Answer (score 1):

All routes are only being set during the config phase.
what happens in your code is that 'todo' route is ignored during the initiation of ngRoute.

What you should do is to setup the route but have a resolve like so:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/todo', {
    templateUrl: 'views/todo.html',
    controller: 'TodoCtrl',
    resolve: {
      todoRef: ['$q', function($q) {
        return todoRef ? todoRef : $q.reject('no ref');
      }]
    }
  });
}]);
```

If 'todoRef' is undefined the route is rejected.

Also you should consider moving 'todoRef' into a service and not on global scope.

---

You can also listen for route errors and for example redirect to home route:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function() {
    $location.path('/home');
  });
}]);
```

Comment: thanks for the response! when i placed your code in the route provider it gives this console error when i try and visit the URL  /#/todo without clicking on the category (ReferenceError: $q is not defined;)  my live example has been updated to show this. 
http://charliebois.com/angular/

Comment: is it possible to have it go back to /home instead of just staying at that url if its undefined? your suggestion did work but it just sits at /todo page

Comment: that worked exactly how I wanted it to! Also quick question to your point about not using todoRef in global scope and putting it in a service, im still fairly new with angular, by moving it into a service are you referring to a factory or just injecting the todoRef as a dependency into the controllers?

Comment: you should learn more about services and DI. notice that the resolve param of $routeProvider injects the keys as local services to the controller. read here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider